# How to save selected dropdown item to database table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a dropdownlist that im fetching from my database and displaying in my php file  as follows:

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
//get a reference to the select element
var $select = $('#bananas');

//request the JSON data and parse into the select element
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1/folder/bananas.json', function(data){

  //clear the current content of the select
  $select.html('');

  //iterate over the data and append a select option
  $.each(data.allbananas, function(key, val){ 
    $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
  })
});
```

my html file

```
<select id="bananas" class="form-control">
 <option value="">-- Select A Banana -- </option></select>
```

But i need user to select each banana from a form and when he or she submits it must be saved to a different table using php.How do i do this,seeing as the dropdownlist is coming from a json file?
Ajax solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:
on Select option change, update a table?
Try this..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="bananas">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
       $("#bananas").change(function(){
           // var option holds the selected option value whenever changed
       var option = $("#bananas").val();
        console.log(option);

           /*
          It would be better practice to add the data to a DB like mySQL and then generating a JSON file from there
          However you can just send this information as you already wanted this way
           */
           $.ajax({
               url: './myphpfile.php',
               data:
               {
                   option:option
               }
           }).done(function(resp){
               if(resp == 200) {
                   console.log("Success!");
               }else if(resp == 0){
                   console.log("Failed..");
               }
           });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: i am not using a php file for the dropdown list.I am accessing a json file and creating the dropdown array.The json file was already created using a php file.Hence not sure how the /myphpfile.php would apply.Please eleborate

Comment: I made a note before the Ajax Request explaining why- "It would be better practice to add the data to a DB like mySQL and then generating a JSON file from there
          However you can just send this information as you already wanted this way"    You could send the data to the JSON file from there instead as you had if you like :)